# How do I loop through an array python with apply?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, for-loop

### My question is, how can I do it without using more than one for-loop?

---

```
#Example:
#samples : [0.1, -0.3]
#return : [0.5, -0.5]

import numpy as np

vq = np.array([-1.5,-0.5,0.5,1.5]) 
vd = np.array([-1,0,1,2])
samples = [0.1,-0.3]

k = []


   g = []

   for t in range(len(vq)):
       if(i[t] == True):
          g.insert(t,vq[t])

   k.append(g[0])

b = []

for n in range(len(samples)):
    i = samples[n] < vd
    b.append(i)

def v(e,m):
   if(m == len(b)):
       return k

   if(b[m][e] == True):
       k.append(vq[e])
       return v(e,m+1)
    else:
        m = m - 1
        return v(e+1,m)
```

How could I use it? I'm trying to use a function.
...................................................

Comment: I have the correct output, I'm asking for a better alternative: making it responsive (or at max using on for-loop).

Comment: How could I use, for example, lambda function ?

Comment: @Adath It's probably best to keep your question focused on what you initially asked. I'm not sure if you need a lambda. What do you mean by "the closest values of vq"?

Comment: for example, the first element of sample's array is 0.1 and in vq array the closest value is 0.5, so it should appear 0.5.

Comment: I wanna use only one for-loop to loop through the samples array

Comment: I only see 1 for loop.  But your indentation is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like (1 for-loop in a list comprehension):

```
In []:
[vq[np.where(vd > x)][0] for x in samples]

Out[]:
[0.5, -0.5]
```

No `for` loops (not recommended!!!):

```
In []:
np.vectorize(lambda x: vq[np.where(vd > x)][0])(samples)

Out[]:
array([ 0.5, -0.5])
```

Comment: There is a way for not using the for?

Comment: There isn't "more than 1 for-loop" as per your question, but yes you can but you are just hiding the for-loop with a module call, see update.

Comment: Don't hide a simple loop with `vectorize`. It's a bad practise.

Comment: Agreed, perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Could use it with lambda instead of for?

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: What's the use of lambda?  It's just a way of defining a function.  You could use it with `map`, but that's a loop with a different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

assuming "closest" value, you may consider `abs`.

```
[vq[np.argmin(abs(j-vq))] for j in samples]
[0.5, -0.5]
```

so you wouldn't need lambda, but in case you want to know how it works or maybe your problem is more complex, the same operation with lambda is;

```
my_lambda = lambda x, y: [x[np.argmin(abs(j-x))] for j in y]
my_lambda (vq, samples)
[0.5, -0.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop at all. First observe that you can find the closest value in `vq` by comparing to values in `vd`. For example, a sample will be closest to `-0.5` if it is between `-1` and `0`.
As `vq` and `vd` are sorted you can use the aptly named `searchsorted` method to search for the indices in `vd` where the samples fit in. These indices applied to `vq` reference the corresponding closest values:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> vq = np.array([-1.5,-0.5,0.5,1.5]) 
>>> vd = np.array([-1,0,1,2])
>>> samples = [0.1,-0.3]
>>> 
>>> vq[vd[:-1].searchsorted(samples)]
array([ 0.5, -0.5])
```

Technical note: before applying searchsorted it is useful to remove the last element from `vd` since it is not in between values of `vq`. Without this precaution a sample > 2 would yield an out-of-bounds index.